# MYSQL Creating a tree/org structure from flat table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to tackle this issue with my limited knowledge of SQL.

I have one table with several rows of employees. Each employee reports to a MGRID. The data can go as 7-8 levels deep, with an employee reporting to a manager, manager to sr. manager, sr. manager to director, and so on.

My table looks like this:

```
EMPID   NAME        MGRID
1       Alex        8
2       Jane        9
3       Bob         10
4       Shack       11
5       Chris       8
6       Sarah       10
7       James       8
8       Michelle    11
9       Ana         11  
10      Steve       11
11      Ron         NULL. <= CEO
12      Mike        3
13      Jenn        3
```

My ultimate goal is to output something that looks like this (multi-level)

```
Ron
    Shack
    Steve
        Bob
            Mike
            Jenn
        Sarah
    Ana
        Jane
    Michelle
        James
        Chris   
        Alex
        Chris
```

Currently on a mysql development environment with version 5.6, and local environment with ver 8.0.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have the relationship structure down in your table; is your question how to output the data in the format described above using a query?

Comment: @NickSuwyn Thanks for the reply. My question is in regards to the actual query and outputting the data in a new format that displays in the form of a hierarchy/tree.

Comment: There may be a way to accomplish this, but it would be quite a hack. This type of output is not a common, or intended, feature of a relational database. Generally, you would write a program to query the db and then you could loop over the result set to print the data to a console or file. Sorry I can't help with your initial end goal, but you might consider looking at the issue from a different angle.

Comment: @NickSuwyn thanks for the feedback. I'll explore some other options, possibly with PHP or JS, since I'm learning about those two languages specifically. Appreciate your support!

Comment: No problem. That sounds like a better direction; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

After lots of searching I found a solution that generates the results I'm looking for (or at least very close to what I need). I'm posting this answer for anyone else who may be looking.

```
WITH RECURSIVE descendants AS
 (
  SELECT EMPID, NAME, MGRID,  1 as level 
   FROM `EMPTABLE`
    WHERE MGRID = NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.EMPID, t.NAME, t.MGRID, d.level+1
    FROM descendants d, `EMPTABLE` t
    WHERE t.MGRID = d.EMPID
    )
SELECT * FROM descendants ORDER BY level;
```

This was the resource I found https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes-part-four-depth-first-or-breadth-first-traversal-transitive-closure-cycle-avoidance/